# How theano.function can be the input of another function in python?

Tags: python, function, theano

I have two .py files. In one of them, I have this function:

```
    def score_semeval2015_term(pred_fn, nnet_outdir, data_dir):
  def predict(dataset):
    x_test = numpy.load(os.path.join(data_dir, 'semeval_{}_x.npy').format(dataset))
    x_test_term = numpy.load(os.path.join(data_dir, 'semeval_{}_x_term.npy').format(dataset))
    print dataset, x_test.shape
    predictions = pred_fn(x_test, x_test_term)
    y2label = {0: 'negative', 1: 'neutral', 2: 'positive'}
    labels = [y2label[y] for y in predictions]
    return labels
```

while pred_fn is a theano.function defined in another .py file as follows:

```
pred_fn = theano.function(inputs=inputs_pred,
                        outputs=predictions,
                        givens=givens_pred)
```

My question is that how it is possible that a function be as an input to the other function? How should I get the input of score_semeval2015_term(pred_fn, nnet_outdir, data_dir) function when I call it?
Thank you.